# What does it imply for partial derivates to be linear combination of each other?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

I'm looking for critical points for the following function for which I know there are an infinite number:

$$ f(x, y) = x^2 + 4y^2 - 4xy + 2 $$

I get partial derivatives:

$$ f_x(x, y) = 2x - 4y $$
$$ f_y(x, y) = -4x + 8y $$

But when I set these equal to 0, I get an identity:

$$ -4x + 8y = 0 $$
$$ x = 2y $$

$$ 2x - 4y = 0 $$
$$ 2(2y) - 4y = 0 $$
$$ 0 = 0 $$

The two partial derivative are just linear combinations of each other. Does this along with the identity I get when deriving critical points in some way prove that the equation has infinitely many critical points?

Comment: The function clearly is constant with value $2$ along the line $x=2y$.

Comment: Notice that you can also complete the square, that is, $$f(x)=x^2+4y^2-4xy+2=(x-2y)^2+2$$ so the function is always $\geqslant2$ and $=2$ only on the line $x=2y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many critical points because $(x,y)$ is a critical point if and only if $x=2y$. In other words$$\{\text{critical points of }f\}=\{(2y,y)\mid y\in\Bbb R\},$$which is an infinite set.